# Java - Find largest number in array using recursion

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I'm trying to use recursion to find the largest number in the array, but am not getting the results i hoped. Any help would be very appreciated.

```
public class ArrayMax {
    public static int largestInteger(int[] array) {

        return FindlargestInteger(array, 0, -99999999);

    }   

    public static int FindlargestInteger(int[] array, int index, int max) { 

        if (index == array.length)
            return max;

        if (array[index] > max) {
            max = array[index];
        }

        FindlargestInteger(array, index + 1, max);

        return max;     
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to return the value of FindlargestInteger

Comment: Sidebar comment: use `Integer.MIN_VALUE` instead of `-99999999`

Answer (score 5):

You need to `return` a call to the function for your function to be recursive.

```
return FindlargestInteger(array, index + 1,max);
```

---

### Code

```
public static int FindlargestInteger(int[] array, int index,int max){   
    if(index == array.length)
        return max;

    if (array[index] > max){
        max = array[index];
    }
    return FindlargestInteger(array, index + 1,max);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `FindlargestInteger` method doesn't currently recurse. You need to first start with a base case; if you're at the end of the array return the last element; otherwise return the largest of the element at the current index or the result of recursing. And, you don't need to pass `max` into the function. You can do it with something like<sup>1</sup>,

```
public static int FindlargestInteger(int[] array, int index) {
    if (index < array.length - 1) {
        return Math.max(array[index], FindlargestInteger(array, index + 1));
    }
    return array[array.length - 1];
}
```

If the goal wasn't recursion, and you're using Java 8+, you *might* also implement it with a one line method using an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) like

```
return IntStream.of(array).max();
```

<sup>1<sub>Please follow Java method naming conventions, method names should start with a lower case letter. As is, your method looks like a constructor.</sub></sup>